# How to read this switch data

Tags: switches, schematics

I'm come across a schematic that uses a switch symbol shown below. This switch is a Kraus & Naimer CA10 Switch (That's all I know). The schematic symbol is shown on the right with terminals numbered 1-6 and lines representing the three positions. The physical location and angle of these positions is shown on the left. Has anyone seen this before and could tell me how to read these or direct me to somewhere showing how?

[image]

I'll shown another example below.

[image]

Comment: The technical notes by each switch define the operation of the contacts. Both seem to have a spring return to default positions. These types of switches trigger or stop a process, so they will not behave like common toggle on/off switches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Each switch position is represented by a vertical line.
- Contacts are arranged horizontally.
- Contact closure is indicated by a black dot.

[image]

*Figure 1.*

- Position A: 5 is connected to 6.
- Position B: 3 is connected to 4.
- Position C: 3 is connected to 4. 1 is connected to 2.

This is rather like a car's ignition + starter switch with 5 - 6 closed in the off position. Turn 90° clockwise for ignition on and a further 30° for starter. When released from the start position it will spring back to ignition position.

[image]

*Figure 2.*

- Position A: no contact.
- Position B: 5 is connected to 6.
- Position C: 3 is connected to 4.
- Position D: 3 is connected to 4. 1 is connected to 2.

Note that in this case A and D the switch springs back to the adjacent position.